# EF Migrations: Truncate table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on an existing project that uses Entity-Framework with code-first. I need to run some SQL before the migrations run, but I get an error regarding foreign-key constraint, so I'll need to delete existing data from tables. Can I do that without deleting the tables using DbMigration.DropTable() ?

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found it:

```
Sql("Truncate table dbo.MyTable");
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but I solved it by manually adding sql to the MigrationBuilder. Just in case this saves someone else a few minutes of searching...

```
migrationBuilder.Operations.Add(new SqlOperation
{
    Sql = "delete from WhateverTable"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't truncate tables referenced with a foreign key constraint.

Your only option is to truncate data manually using `DELETE FROM` starting from the table that's not referenced by any other table. The EF equivalent would be something like

```
db.TableToTruncate.RemoveRange(db.TableToTruncate);
```

Comment: I understand, but in my case I don't really need the data from them and I also have an sql script to populate them.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In some case in production environment you don't have population scripts, and you need the content of your table. In that case you can use DbMigration.DropForeignKey and DbMigration.AddForeignKey functions or create a MyTableCopy table, run your SQL and insert the content of MyTable to your new table. After that in a new migration you can delete your original table and rename your new table.

Comment: For me the data was not important, this is why i wanted to truncate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem in .net core EF. so i added below code.

```
await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(
            "Truncate only public.\"TableName\" RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I solved it by adding SQL command to the MigrationBuilder like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
     migrationBuilder.Operations.Add(new SqlOperation
     {
          Sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE your_table_name",
     });
     .
     .
     .
     .
}
```